# Flex-lexer: later rule get priority over prior rule

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to extract information from a c/c++ sourcefile. 
I'm trying to extract the content of a Macro.

E.g.:

- From `MYMACRO(random content)` `random content` should be extracted.
- From `MYMACRO (random content)` `random content` should be extracted.

**Problem:**
Bison won't recognice `MYMACRO` as a token.

This code is only the first step and expects only the Macro itself as an input

**Lex-File: parser.l**

```
%{
 #include <iostream>
 #include "parser.tab.h"
 using namespace std;
 extern int yylex(); 
%}

%option noyywrap

%%

"MYMACRO" {
  return EXTRACT_CONTENT_START;
}

[(] {
  return BRACE_OPEN;
}

[)] {
  return BRACE_CLOSE; 
}

.* { 
    yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);
    return ANY_TEXT;
}


%%
```

**bison-file: parser.y:**

```
%{

  #include <iostream>
  #include <string.h>
  using namespace std;

  extern int yylex();
  extern int yyparse();
  extern int yy_scan_string(char const *);

  void yyerror(const char *s);

%}

%union {
  int ival;
  char * sval;
  char cval;
}

%error-verbose


%token EXTRACT_CONTENT_START
%token <cval> BRACE_OPEN
%token <cval> BRACE_CLOSE
%token <sval> ANY_TEXT

%%

program:
    EXTRACT_CONTENT_START 
    BRACE_OPEN
    ANY_TEXT
    BRACE_CLOSE 
    ;

%%

int main(int ,char**){
  yy_scan_string("MYMACRO(random content)");
  yyparse();
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
  cout << endl << s << endl;
  exit(-1);
}
```

- **expected:** `random content`
- **actual:** `unexpected ANY_TEXT, expecting EXTRACT_CONTENT_START`
  ( So @Flex: instead of sending the first appearing rule, the last rule is actual being used)

I've also tried using states and change the last rule in the flex-file to

```
<STATE_CONTENT> .* { 
    yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);
    return ANY_TEXT;
}
```

But this will result in an `unrecognized rule` error on the line containint `%%`.

Comment: You need a rule to ignore whitespace.

Comment: I added an answer with my latest findings. Whitespace does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: You cannot put whitespace before the pattern, whether or not it is preceded by a state. Another way of saying that, which is technically more accurate, is that patterns cannot contain unquoted whitespace, and the `<STATE>` prefix is part of the pattern.

Comment: @rici: Thank you! That really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason, why the last rule is taken in preference:

lex uses *the longest match*. And .* fits more characters, than anything else. Therefore ANY_TEXT is always the taken choice.

To solve it change it like this:

**parser.l**:

remove `.*`-rule and add this one:

```
. { 
    yylval.cval = *yytext;
    return ANY_CHAR;
}
```

This rule's longest match is only *one* character. It will therefore be on lowest priority comparing to the other rules.

**parser.y**:

Add a new token:

```
%token <cval> ANY_CHAR
```

For acting on the whole string, add:

```
  anyText:
      anyText ANY_CHAR { cout << $2; }    
      |
  ;
```

**@State problem:**  Answer from rici:

> You cannot put whitespace before the pattern, whether or not it is preceded by a state. Another way of saying that, which is technically more accurate, is that patterns cannot contain unquoted whitespace, and the  prefix is part of the pattern